Make azure web app proxy to make request from another country
I need is make a request to an url that only allows access from certain countries, so I figured I could use a proxy server in one of these countries, and make the request using it.
So far, I see a proxy as an option, but I want to make sure it's legal and possible, for example using this code (ideal before purchasing the proxy service):
   var proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy-server:port");

   
    // proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = proxy,
        UseProxy = true // Asegura que se use el proxy
    };

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://example.com");

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

